# How to run a Web-Driver in a 32-bit Linux?

Tags: python, linux, selenium, x86, raspberry-pi-zero

**How to run a Web-Driver in a 32-bit Linux?**

Recently I bought a pi zero 2 and I have a script which uses selenium, it worked on 64-bit Ubuntu witch chrome but I cant get it right on Pi-Os because it's a 32-bit system.

There is a 32 bit Web-Driver but it's internet explorer, and it isn't supported on Linux,
Opera has no 32-bit variant,

Do I have to wait for 64 bit OS for my pi?

Comment: Even ignoring the 32bits problem, I don't think you will be able to run selenium on a device with only 512MB of RAM...

Comment: This makes it sound like you can already install a 64-bit OS on your Pi: https://ubuntu.com/blog/raspberry-pi-zero-2-w-with-ubuntu-server-support-is-here

Comment: I don't have another pi for Ubuntu core, and Ubuntu server isn't as functional as PiOS